# ASP.NET WebAPI Identity Entity Framework Database-First model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, identity, database-first

I would like to ask you how can I implement DB First model in ASP.NET Identity Scheme. When I create a WebAPI project with individual user authentication I can see code-first model with some implementation in it. I am trying to solve this and I was searching for some solution but i didnt found it. Do you know about any good tutorials or just the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Models need not be present always inside Model folder of web-api project.
They can be from other dlls as well.
I would suggest you to create a new project for your Data Access Layer, and add the EF databasefirst dbml to that project. Later refer it in your web-api project to use it.